# Having cordova 6.4.0 and wanna install cordova 6.0.0

Tags: cordova

Currently I have the version 6.4.0 of cordova installed in my computer.
I got it after executing this cmd:

```
npm install -g cordova@latest
```

But now as required in my tsak, I have to get cordova `6.0.0` installed.

How Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simpler than I thought:

```
npm install -g cordova@6.0.0
```